# Is there a simple recipe for listening to RTL2832U FM-Radio?

Tags: dvb-t

This is on Ubuntu 12.04 - I installed the DVB-Realteck-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel package, I installed GnuRadio, I installed the rtl_fm and I just keep getting more and more confused -- I recognize that this device can monitor police radio, digital FM, weather channels, you name it, but all I really need is to run a simple command line and hear a plain ordinary FM station streaming through my speakers.

The closest so far is the command:

```
rtl_fm -f 96.3e6 -s 48000 - | aplay -r raw -f dat -c 1
```

but the sound quality is atrocious.

Any and all guesses or pointers to resources are welcome. I haven't been able to find anything through the Google searches that gets me any closer to a nice clean stereo FM signal.  GnuRadio seems completely intractable although I am certain that, once one figures out what it is that it does, it makes perfect sense ;)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
rtl_fm -f 96.3e6 -W -s 200000 -r 48000 - | aplay -r 48k -f S16_LE
```

Note FM Radio is a wide FM signal!

`rtl_fm` make as default NFM (narrow fm).

Comment: Does this play back in stereo or mono?